# How to test such class behavior in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a class which is responsible for dealing with some response from payments gateway.

Let's say:

```
class PaymentReceiver
  def initialize(gateway_response)
    @gateway_response = gateway_response
  end

  def handle_response
    if @gateway_response['NC_STATUS'] != '0'
      if order
        order.fail_payment
      else
        raise 'LackOfProperOrder'
        # Log lack of proper order
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def order
    @order ||= Order.where(id: @gateway_response['orderID']).unpaid.first
  end
end
```

In payload from payment I've `NC_STATUS`
which is responsible for information if payment succeed and `orderID` which refers to `Order ActiveRecord class by`id`.

I would like to test behavior(in rspec):
If PaymentReceiver receives response where NC_STATUS != 0 sends `fail_payment` to specific `Order` object referred by `orderID`.

How you would approach to testing this ? I assume that also design could be bad ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make refactorization to remove `SRP` and `DIR` principles violations.
Something below I'd say:

```
class PaymentReceiver
  def initialize(response)
    @response = response
  end

  def handle_response
    if @response.success?
       @response.order.pay
    else
       @response.order.fail_payment
    end
  end
end

# it wraps output paramteres only !
class PaymentResponse
  def initialize(response)
    @response = response
  end

  def order
    # maybe we can check if order exists
    @order ||= Order.find(@response['orderID'].to_i)
  end

  def success?
    @response['NCSTATUS'] == '0'
  end
end

p = PaymentReceiver.new(PaymentResponse({'NCSTATUS' => '0' }))
p.handle_response
```

Then testing everything is easy.